# Show how many Polygons are overlapping in different styles

Tags: qgis, layers, overlapping-features

First of all I use QGIS. I got a bunch of polygons that describe a 10 min. footway from different addresses.

What I want to do now is to illustrate the areas where the polygons are overlapping. My trouble is how to show the differences between 2 overlapping polygons and 3, 4 or 5 overlapping ones.

My idea is to do some query where I get a Layer with all those overlaps and in one column of the attribute table it says how many polygons are overlapping. I hope the attachment helps to understand what I'm looking for.

[image: Attachment]

Do you have any idea how to do that?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, a simple "Intersection" tool (in the Processing Toolbox) is what you need. It can be done even if the polygons are the same layer

Comment: Could [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/260113/convert-polygon-to-grid-lines/263666#263666) be a possibility?

Comment: Thanks a lot, Kazuhito! That's excactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

With respect to styling / display, you don't even need to compute the number of intersecting polygons. Open the layer style and set the `feature blending mode` to `addition` (while in there, you may want to test other modes)

[image: Feature blending mode - addition]